# Microsoft Graph with OneDrive for Business - remove item from 'Shared with me' list

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe` I can get a list of all items shared with me and by default all these files are displayed in 'Shared with me' tab in OneDrive for Business.

Through the browser it's possible to remove specified item from this list by clicking on it and removing, so item no longer is displayed but I still can access it.

The request is made to:

```
https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/personal/{user}/_api/SP.Sharing.DocumentSharingManager.RemoveItemsFromSharedWithMeView
```

Can I remove item from this list using graph.microsoft.com endpoint or Microsoft Graph .NET Client library?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no support for removing an item from the shared with me list using OneDrive or Graph APIs/SDKs. But you bring up a good point. I will make a note of it and see if this is something we can add support for.

Comment: Does the Microsoft Graph API already support this functionality?

Comment: @Kashif Tahir, Where did you find this information? I see only that there are no any documentation about it, but I don't see anything about "no support". Can you please share the link.

Comment: @megabyte1024, looks like no :( and there are no explanation about it.